# Returning a constructor with another class' data members? Getting conversion errors?

Tags: c++

We are given a driver file and input file. We are tasked at creating a header and source file, which I have created and added below.

The issue I'm having is we are asked to return a `PassageToken` but the compiler is asking to convert it first, because I'm unaware of what the return type would be. I believe I might need to overload an operator?

error: could not convert 'PassageToken(std::__cxx11::basic_string(((StoryTokenizer*)this)->StoryTokenizer::nameP), std::__cxx11::basic_string(((StoryTokenizer*)this)->StoryTokenizer::textP), std::__cxx11::basic_string(((StoryTokenizer*)this)->StoryTokenizer::passnumP))' from 'PassageToken' to 'StoryTokenizer'
   return PassageToken(nameP, textP, passnumP);

error: conversion from 'StoryTokenizer' to non-scalar type 'PassageToken'

Comment: `StoryTokenizer::nextPassage()` should return a `PassageToken` not a `std::string`. Your function doesn't match with the function prototype.

Comment: Unrelated: [The Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests that you do not need destructors for your classes. You can save yourself a bit of coding. While you're reading the link, Familiarize yourself with the Rule of Three. Knowing when and where to apply it can save you a lot of debugging time later.

Comment: Recommendation: When you have a compiler error, avoid posting code fragments. If I try to compile your code to duplicate the error, I will get many more errors and maybe not the one you are hunting. Instead back up your code and produce a program that has the exact same error but as little code as possible. Often the reduction in code leaves the cause of the problem too little room to hide and you can fix the problem yourself without having to ask a question. Use [mcve] as inspiration.

Comment: I'm sorry, if it isn't obvious I'm still new to this and have a lot to learn.

@aep when I set PassageToken as the function type it tells me error

Comment: @kingk Can you please post a [MCVE(minimally complete veriable example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that the community can know the exact error you're talking about.

Comment: @aep as a separate question or edit the question?

Comment: @kingk Editing the same question should be fine.

Comment: When you ask for help resolving an error, you should copy the exact error message into your question. The interpretation of an error message by someone who is not able to resolve the error is suspect.

Comment: Is this better? This problem is complex as I cannot edit the driver file. I hope it is much clearer now.

Comment: `StoryTokenizer StoryTokenizer::nextPassage()` the return value should be `PassageToken` i.e. `PassageToken StoryTokenizer::nextPassage()`.

Comment: Doing that yields error: 'PassageToken' does not name a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes we make small mistakes that we overlook and spend hours debugging. Here the issues was requesting a `PassageToken` type before declaring it. The simple solution was to place the `PassageToken` class before the `StoryTokenizer` class so it can recognize it as a type.